# Add a key/value to Redis in Nginx

Tags: nginx, lua, redis, openresty

I would like to communicate with redis from nginx, in order to store in lists which requests have been made on images especially on images not founds that are proxied on another server.

I installed OpenResty, in order to use `redis2_query` and `redis2_pass` commands.

Here is my nginx config :

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ {
    try_files $uri @imagenotfound;

    redis2_query lpush founds $uri;
    redis2_pass 127.0.0.1:6379;

}

location @imagenotfound {

    proxy_pass http://imgdomain.com/$uri;
    proxy_set_header Host imgdomain.com;
    proxy_set_header Server imgdomain.com;

    redis2_query lpush notfounds $uri;
    redis2_pass 127.0.0.1:6379;

}
```

Every request i make returns an integer, and, as i understand, `redis2_pass` returns the result of the query. Is there anyway to not return this result and just execute the query?

If i remove the `redis2_query` and `redis2_pass`, the images are displayed correctly.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: why is this a problem? Is it because you get those in an HTTP response? Not at all confortable with this nginx module, so just trying to understand the issue to see if I can help.

Comment: because i want nginx to return the image, not an integer that is the result of the redis query...

Comment: I'm not the best person to help, so this is a random though. But would it help just finishing the `location` method with `$uri`?

Comment: I'm new to this module too! As i understand, this module allows to store data in redis as cache and retrieve it with redis_pass. I just need to store data in redis.
Could you please give an example of your suggestion? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What happens if you put the redis directives first?

Comment: @LinusGThiel in the first location, the value is stored in redis but the image is not displayed (it returns the integer). In the second location, the image is displayed (with proxy_pass) but no data is stored in redis...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that seems to work is to use Lua scripts with access_by_lua and the resty.redis module :

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ {
    try_files $uri @imagenotfound;

    access_by_lua '
                    local redis = require "resty.redis"
                    local red = redis:new()
                    red:set_timeout(1000)
                    local ok, err = red:connect("127.0.0.1", 6379)
                    if not ok then
                        ngx.say("failed to connect: ", err)
                        return
                    end
                    ok, err = red:lpush("founds", ngx.var.uri)
                    if not ok then
                        ngx.say("failed to set founds: ", err)
                        return
                    end
            ';


}

location @imagenotfound {

    proxy_pass http://imgdomain.com/$uri;
    proxy_set_header Host imgdomain.com;
    proxy_set_header Server imgdomain.com;

     access_by_lua '
                    local redis = require "resty.redis"
                    local red = redis:new()
                    red:set_timeout(1000)
                    local ok, err = red:connect("127.0.0.1", 6379)
                    if not ok then
                        ngx.say("failed to connect: ", err)
                        return
                    end
                    ok, err = red:lpush("notfounds", ngx.var.uri)
                    if not ok then
                        ngx.say("failed to set notfounds: ", err)
                        return
                    end
            ';


}
```

If anyone has Lua skills and can tell me if it's the right way to do it, i would be glad to have his feedback!

Anyway, thanks for your help in comments.